# Objective-C pointer values

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers

I'm compiling an application using X-Code 3.2.6 (64-bit).  The application is compiling against the 10.5 SDK and in 32 Bit Intel Architecture.

I've declared a character array as:

```
char iptmp[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

so I'm calling a function thus:

```
myfunc(&iptmp);
```

Where myfunc is declared:

```
void myfunc(char** value)
{
  ...
};
```

With the intention of loading the character array with the contents of another string with strncpy.  When you see what's below you might appreciate why I don't simply do something like:  strcpy(iptmp, myfunc());  but here is the problem:

```
Value of iptmp prior to function call:  0xb0206f5a
Value of *value in function:            0xffffb020
```

I've tried various things to resolve this problem, but the only thing that seems to stick is to receive a UINT32 value and cast:

```
myfunc((UINT32) &iptmp);

void myfunc(UINT32 value)
{
  char* target = (char*) value;

  ...
}
```

This is causing havoc in my code.  What is going on with the pointer value?

Comment: @Athabaska: the OP's on the money. `iptmp` is of type `char*`, so `&iptmp` *is* a `char**`. EDIT: as far as that's concerned, anyway...

Comment: @Mac: That is incorrect.  `iptmp` is of type `char [ARRAY_SIZE]`, which is entirely different to `char *` (though the former is useable as the latter in some contexts), and `&iptmp` is consequently of type `char (*)[ARRAY_SIZE]`, which again is entirely different to `char **` (and *never* interchangeable).

Comment: @caf: I may have been a bit hasty. Right you are! :)

Answer (score 4):

What happens here is that `iptmp` is a location in memory. If you write `iptmp` you will get the address of the aray. However, you will *also* get the address of it if you write `&iptmp`. However, you assume that you will get a pointer to a pointer to the array.

The best way to handle this is simply doing:

```
void myfunc(char * value)
{
  ...
};
```

The pointer `value` will point to the array, which you can modify anyway you like.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
void myfunc(char *value)
{
  strncpy(value, ...);
}
```

and

```
myfunc(iptmp);
```

Remember, arrays and pointers in C are not the same things, although you may have heard the opposite many times. An array is an object whose size is equal to its length multiplied by the size of each of its elements, while a pointer is just like a single `int` but with special semantics.

Hence, the two expressions `iptmp` and `&iptmp` yield the same result, namely the starting address of the array. `iptmp` yields a pointer value for convenience, but that doesn't mean that the object `iptmp` is a pointer itself.

By attempting to get the address of the address of the array, you really intend to perform `&(&iptmp)`, which is a meaningless, erroneous operation.

Comment: Thanks. Getting too close to the problem. In this context what you suggest is OK and works.
My tracing is telling me that the value for char* is being passed faithfully too, but this is not the case for char**.  So my question still stands.

Comment: @mbb: You don't need a pointer to a pointer to do what you want to do. However, if this is *really* what a pointer to a pointer, then you would have to create a real, physical pointer to point to. as in `char iptmp[...]; char * pointer = &iptmp; myfunc(&pointer);`.

Comment: Thanks.  Once again too close to the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you derefence `*value`, you're saying "take the pointer stored in `value`, and load the bytes at that location as if they were a `char *`".  But the bytes at the location pointed to by `value` *aren't* a `char *` - they're the first bytes of `iptmp[]` itself (in your case, the first 4 bytes).

The root cause is that you're passing `&iptmp`, which has type `char (*)[ARRAY_SIZE]`, to a function that expects a `char **` parameter.  These types are not interchangeable, as you've found.  The correct declaration for the function would be:

```
void myfunc(char (*value)[ARRAY_SIZE])
{
    /* ... */
}
```

You can then pass `&iptmp`, and you will find that `*value` has the value that you expect.